# How to train Prediction model for longitudinal data, with large number of time points?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, multiple-regression, panel-data

Given a longitudinal data, that has date (in *month-year* format) as one of the independent variables and other independent variables being Gross metric tonnes, Tensile strength(UTS), weight per unit length, Zone of rail track and dependent variable - number of rail failures for rail track, what is the good way for building a prediction model for the data. Date ranges from January-2010 to December-2019 (120 time points). The columns GMT, UTS, Zone, Weight are not time series but rather cross-sectional data.

Data looks like -

```
Zone | Time     | GMT        |  UTS | Weight | RF  |    
 CR  | jan-2010 | >100       |  880 | 52Kg   | 90  |
 NR  | feb-2010 | 100 to 200 | 1080 | 60 kg  | 110 |
 NFR | jan-2010 | >100       |  880 |  52 kg | 112 |                           
                               :
```

I have thought about following ways -

1) Making seperate time series for each combination of independent variables. But this will lead to nearly 400 time series, making it tedious to study all the time series seperately.

2) Using time as regressor variable.If time is considered to be categorical variable and is encoded using integer encoding, then the effects like seasonality and auto-correlation in time series can't be modelled. If time is encoded with one-hot encoding method, then about 120 dummy variables need to be created.

3) Adding lag values to the data and using it as regressor along with time regressor. But, I am not sure is this the correct way as I read it is not good practice.

4) Using Fixed Effect / Random Effect model. It is mostly used in Econometrics and when T(number of time points) is lesser than number of parameters, which is not the case.

Which from above mentioned ways is the best ? Is there any better way of doing panel data prediction?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can train in self supervised way your 4D time series. 
You can use a convolutionnal network you will have 4 inputs channels.
You will use then a MSE loss between your input let's says last 2048 points and prediction set at the 256 points for example.
In order to achieve a good accuracy you can train a convolutionnal VAE autoencodeur and use the encoder in your convolutionnal network for prediction.
Like :
Input -> Encode -> feedForward -> prediction

Comment: Hi, joseph  thanks for answering. I don't have much knowledge about Neural networks. But, the data I have is not 4D time series. Only time series available in the given data is RF- number of rail failures.

Comment: I was a bit fast, basically you have 4 times series right :
 - GMT
 - UTS
 - Weight
 - RF
Means 4 features, -> for 1d time series -> you can converte into 1 image with 4 channels representing your 4 features ( 1 channel per feature)

Comment: A simpler Markov regression model may work.  A first-order Markov process would just use the lag-1 value of failures as a new covariate.  Estimation uses standard regression or machine learning.  Once estimates are obtained you can marginalize over the lags to get state occupancy characteristics.   A semiparametric model may also help with distributional assumptions for failures.  See [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/markov).